# django obtain a value from a determinated queryset with a string?

Tags: django, database, django-queryset

I want to get or obtain the data from a selected queryset with a string, something like this:

```
queryset= BasicModel.objects.all()
x = 10
my_atribute = "name"
queryset[x]["my_atribute"]
```

`values()` don't work, because it's give me, in ForeingKeys model, the key and not the data.

Comment: Is `my_attribute` an attribute on your model?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: What's wrong with just using the `dot notation: queryset[x].my_attribute`?